# Mobile Device Management of Hardware Components?

Tags: android, camera, microphone, mdm

Been looking at mobile device management for tablets. So far many of them provide exactly what we are looking for (allowable apps, IT policy enforecment, etc). however having difficulty with managing the camera and microphone. Can't find one that disables them during certain times of day and location.

I've looked over the adroid API and see that interfacing with the hardware is no problem (proven by how many apps there are that accesses that information).

However, is it possible to create an app that disables (i.e. NO app can access, use, or record from) the camera and microphone?

In my expermentation it seems only one app can consume the camera/microphone at any given time. So I was just thinking if having my custom app consume them and not releasing until IT policy was met (based on proximity, time of day, etc) would be a relatively easy approach.

Or is there a better approach? I know this is kinda open ended question, but I think I have exhausted the OOB MDM side of things and need to turn to software developement.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can look into is Google's official Android Device Policy enforcement for the camera lockdown. However this solution requires you to use a paid version of Google Apps.

Please find more information here in ***device settings***:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408902

It also allows for app's auditing so you can set rules whitelist/blacklist certain apps.

For a custom solution, you can do the same thing by disabling camera using the API under **Policies section**:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

There is not the same feature for microphone. The idea of permanently engaging the microphone to block other sources although may work to block it is overall bad design and potentially (untested) terrible for battery life and renders functionality. But theoretically you should be able to do the that, but I would suggest thoroughly investigating the side effects.